# How build a Spritesheet with pure CSS and JS in React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sprite-sheet

I have a Spritesheet of a bottle of beer and when Scroll down the bottle turns I use the library react-responsive-spritesheet but

but it looks slow because I have other things that change in the Onscroll method.
I've been thinking about replacing the spritesheet with pure css

something like putting all the images on top of each other and changing the z-index of each of them in such a way that you see a fluid turn.

Somebody now what is the best way for build this animation ?

Comment: a spritesheet with css and js sounds a little like using the background-image style on a component, and updating the x, y offset of the image with js as the page scrolls. does that make sense?

Comment: I've seen a page that uses what I want, and by looking as it did through the elements inspector, they place all the photos of the bottles in an envelope of another and change the name of the class dynamically so that only one photo is visible both

Comment: but I can not understand how they do to change the class dynamically many times. page : https://cockta.eu/en/#your_cockta_your_spirit

Comment: yeah, that's not a sprite sheet. it's just a list of images that turn on and off to create an animation. a spritesheet would have all of the drink images in a single very tall or very wide png file--for example--and as the page scrolled you would change which portion of the image was showing and hide the rest.

Comment: what I still do not understand is how to make that loop that deactivates and activates each image